Issue with beacon in saltstack (salt-project)
I am trying to test out creating a beacon and seem to getting a "An un-handled exception was caught by Salt's global exception handler" error.  Any suggestions?
salt-master 3006.9 (Sulfur)
salt-minion 3006.9 (Sulfur)
/etc/salt/minion.d/disk.conf
`beacons:
  diskusage:
    - /: 5%
    - interval: 60`

sudo salt-call state.event pretty=True
__beacons_return    {
    "_stamp": "2024-08-19T15:45:14.797958",
    "beacons": [
        {
            "beacon_name": "diskusage",
            "data": {
                "diskusage": 77.6,
                "id": "hostname",
                "mount": "/"
            },
            "tag": "salt/beacon/hostname/diskusage/"
        }
    ]
}
[ERROR   ] An un-handled exception was caught by Salt's global exception handler:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position 1: invalid continuation byte
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/salt-call", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(salt_call())
  File "/opt/saltstack/salt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/salt/scripts.py", line 444, in salt_call
    client.run()
  File "/opt/saltstack/salt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/salt/cli/call.py", line 50, in run
    caller.run()
  File "/opt/saltstack/salt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/salt/cli/caller.py", line 95, in run
    ret = self.call()
  File "/opt/saltstack/salt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/salt/cli/caller.py", line 200, in call
    ret["return"] = self.minion.executors[fname](
  File "/opt/saltstack/salt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/salt/loader/lazy.py", line 159, in __call__
    ret = self.loader.run(run_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/saltstack/salt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/salt/loader/lazy.py", line 1245, in run
    return self._last_context.run(self._run_as, _func_or_method, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/saltstack/salt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/salt/loader/lazy.py", line 1260, in _run_as
    ret = _func_or_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/saltstack/salt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/salt/executors/direct_call.py", line 10, in execute
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/saltstack/salt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/salt/loader/lazy.py", line 159, in __call__
    ret = self.loader.run(run_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/saltstack/salt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/salt/loader/lazy.py", line 1245, in run
    return self._last_context.run(self._run_as, _func_or_method, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/saltstack/salt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/salt/loader/lazy.py", line 1260, in _run_as
    ret = _func_or_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/saltstack/salt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/salt/modules/state.py", line 2594, in event
    salt.utils.data.decode(ret["data"]),
  File "/opt/saltstack/salt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/salt/utils/data.py", line 252, in decode
    return decode_dict(
  File "/opt/saltstack/salt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/salt/utils/data.py", line 411, in decode_dict
    value = decode(
  File "/opt/saltstack/salt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/salt/utils/data.py", line 293, in decode
    data = _decode_func(data, encoding, errors, normalize)
  File "/opt/saltstack/salt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/salt/utils/stringutils.py", line 113, in to_unicode
    return _normalize(to_str(s, encoding, errors))
  File "/opt/saltstack/salt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/salt/utils/stringutils.py", line 89, in to_str
    raise exc  # pylint: disable=raising-bad-type
  File "/opt/saltstack/salt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/salt/utils/stringutils.py", line 82, in to_str
    return _normalize(s.decode(enc, errors))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position 1: invalid continuation byte
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/salt-call", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(salt_call())
  File "/opt/saltstack/salt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/salt/scripts.py", line 444, in salt_call
    client.run()
  File "/opt/saltstack/salt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/salt/cli/call.py", line 50, in run
    caller.run()
  File "/opt/saltstack/salt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/salt/cli/caller.py", line 95, in run
    ret = self.call()
  File "/opt/saltstack/salt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/salt/cli/caller.py", line 200, in call
    ret["return"] = self.minion.executors[fname](
  File "/opt/saltstack/salt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/salt/loader/lazy.py", line 159, in __call__
    ret = self.loader.run(run_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/saltstack/salt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/salt/loader/lazy.py", line 1245, in run
    return self._last_context.run(self._run_as, _func_or_method, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/saltstack/salt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/salt/loader/lazy.py", line 1260, in _run_as
    ret = _func_or_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/saltstack/salt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/salt/executors/direct_call.py", line 10, in execute
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/saltstack/salt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/salt/loader/lazy.py", line 159, in __call__
    ret = self.loader.run(run_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/saltstack/salt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/salt/loader/lazy.py", line 1245, in run
    return self._last_context.run(self._run_as, _func_or_method, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/saltstack/salt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/salt/loader/lazy.py", line 1260, in _run_as
    ret = _func_or_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/saltstack/salt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/salt/modules/state.py", line 2594, in event
    salt.utils.data.decode(ret["data"]),
  File "/opt/saltstack/salt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/salt/utils/data.py", line 252, in decode
    return decode_dict(
  File "/opt/saltstack/salt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/salt/utils/data.py", line 411, in decode_dict
    value = decode(
  File "/opt/saltstack/salt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/salt/utils/data.py", line 293, in decode
    data = _decode_func(data, encoding, errors, normalize)
  File "/opt/saltstack/salt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/salt/utils/stringutils.py", line 113, in to_unicode
    return _normalize(to_str(s, encoding, errors))
  File "/opt/saltstack/salt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/salt/utils/stringutils.py", line 89, in to_str
    raise exc  # pylint: disable=raising-bad-type
  File "/opt/saltstack/salt/lib/python3.10/site-packages/salt/utils/stringutils.py", line 82, in to_str
    return _normalize(s.decode(enc, errors))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position 1: invalid continuation byte

I am expecting to just receive:
__beacons_return    {
"_stamp": "2024-08-19T15:45:14.797958",
"beacons": [
{
"beacon_name": "diskusage",
"data": {
"diskusage": 77.6,
"id": "hostname",
"mount": "/"
},
"tag": "salt/beacon/hostname/diskusage/"
}
]
}
I have tried different minions to see if it was just the host I am trying, I can see that the beacon is triggering however the exception right afterward.

The event data has an invalid encoding. That's a bug you should report. Possibly because your minion is running with an unsupported locale.

Thanks @OrangeDog I just submitted a Bug report.
